# Почему не отображаются атрибуты? Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Не отображаются атрибуты товаров. Пробовала прописывать названия атрибутов на русском, на английском. Меняла темы. Нет атрибутов. Я так понимаю, что они должны быть под названием категории? Как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/178988

Comment: @Анна Чумаченко, не нужно восстанавливать неправильные метки. Из-за этого вопрос может быть закрыт. Но нужно реагировать на ответы и  комментарии. Отмечать решением те, что помогли.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67758/discussion-on-question-by-------woocom).

Answer (score 3):

В общем случае атрибуты любого товара выводятся во вкладке Additional Information (Дополнительная информация).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Под названием категории выводятся атрибуты только для вариативного товара.

Смотрю на ваш сайт и вижу, что указанный в ссылке товар - не вариативный, а простой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что надо сделать для вывода атрибутов вариативного товара под категорией?

**Создать атрибуты**.

В консоли выберите Products->Atributes и создайте атрибуты.

**Присвоить атрибутам значения**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Сделать товар вариативным и указать его атрибуты**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Создать вариации товара по атрибутам и задать им цену**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот тогда на странице товара вы увидите выбор вариаций и диапазон цен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Атрибуты могут быть и у простых товаров. А ТС  спрашивает об их месте вывода, а не выбора вариаций.

Comment: @SeVlad все равно мы тут между собой переписываемся )) ТС только вопросы задает - ни одного комментария в ответ )

Comment: Атрибуты - это характеристики товаров, они часто нужны, а вот вариации - это то, что необходимо для выбора цвета, размера и т.д.

Comment: ну допустим габариты коробки, производитель, срок гарантии - эта информация, которую необходимо доносить покупателю. В описании это будет смотреться убого, пример: https://rozetka.com.ua/blizzarini_31270_40/p23252778/#tab=characteristics (данная ссылка используется не в целях рекламы)

Comment: Кстати, фильтры товаров используют атрибуты для фильтрации товаров, поэтому это необходимо

Comment: Раз уж вы поняли вопрос, не могли бы вы дополнить его минимальным примером кода?

Comment: @NickVolynkin это стандартный функционал WooCommerce, он не требует кода вообще никакого. Надо создать в консоли сайта атрибуты, товар, присвоить ему атрибуты. То есть это даже не по программированию вопрос, по большому счету.

Comment: @NickVolynkin полагаю, что мой ответ содержит самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример работы с атрибутами товара.

Comment: @KAGGDesign всё же "У такого товара атрибутов быть не может." в ответе не верно ;)

Comment: @SeVlad спс, сейчас поправлю

Comment: `даже не по программированию вопрос` – вот и закроем его как оффтопик )))

Comment: @NickVolynkin можно и так, тогда на Super User его перенести, что ли... Или еще куда

Comment: @KAGGDesign да я шучу. Ну вот такие прикладные вопросы по настройке софта. Ответы на них знают в основном программисты. Другого русскоязычного ресурса с таким же уровнем экспертов наверняка нет по этой теме. Пускай остаются.

Comment: @NickVolynkin формально - надо закрывать с переносом. Но пусть лучше остаются.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, атрибуты всегда выводятся во вкладке доп.информация
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]